# Tensorflow share weights across input placeholder

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network

I am trying to build a neural network with shared input weights.

Given `pk` inputs in the form `X=[x_1, ..., x_p, v_1,...,v_p,z1,...,z_p,...]` and a weight matrix `w`  of shape `(p, layer1_size)`,  I want the  the first layer to be defined as  `sum(w, x_.) + sum(w, v_.) + ...`.

In other words the input and the first layer should be fully connected where weights are shared across the different groups of inputs.  `l = tf.matmul(X, W)` where each row of `W` must have a structure like: `(w1, ... ,wp, w1, ..., wp, ...)`

How can I do that in tensorflow?

Answer (score 1):

A simple option would be to replicate `W`. If the original `W` is, lets say `p X q`, you can just do `l = tf.matmul(X, tf.tile(W, (k, 1)))`.

Comment: I suspect Donbeo is looking for a way of sharing W as a tf.Variable. If you use tile, then W would be duplicated, which means backpropagation would optimize each instance of W differently. The solution required here would need to use just one instance of W which is optimized as a single entity, even though its influence is distributed across groups of inputs.

Comment: @AndrewMedlin Tiling a value of a variable does not make multiple instances of it. There is still one single variable and you use it multiple times; on backpropagation, each of these uses will have a gradient that contribute to the total update of the variable. (Note that my suggestion was not to replace `W` with a variable `k` times bigger, which would be more similar to what you say)

Comment: My apologies, you are correct. To clarify my correction, tf.tile() will make  multiple USES of the tiled variable, but not multiple instances, as jdehesa said.

Answer (score 0):

I think `tf.nn.conv1d` solves your task. Look at: [tf.nn.conv1d documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/tf/nn/conv1d)

Comment: That is an efficient solution, although it would require some reshaping and passing a stride of `k`.

Comment: What is the right way to use it?   If the input is `x_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None,  p, k]) `    how should `W` and the conv1d arguments be defined?

Comment: `X` in your top question has shape `[k * p]` you can reshape it by `tf.reshape` to `[None, k, p]` (`p` is last because `X=[x_1, ..., x_p, v_1,...,v_p,z1,...,z_p,...]`). You should define weights with shape `[k, p, layer1_size]` and `stride=k`, and use `tf.nn.conv1d`

Comment: I'm not sure to understand. `W` should be an operator from a space of dimension `p` to one of dimension `l1_size`.  Why should it be 3 dimensional with `k` as well?

Comment: I was expecting `W.shape = (1, p, l1_size)` or something like that

Comment: Isn't it the right solution  ```x_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None,  k, p])                                                                                                                                                                     
w0 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1, p, l1]))                                                                                                                                                                             
c = tf.nn.conv1d(x_, w0, stride=1, padding='SAME')   ```  ?

Comment: My mistake. Sorry. And you need `tf.reduce_sum` after convolution for reduce `[None, k, l1]` to `[None, l1]`